# macOS how to group and focus more than one labels during VoiceOver accessibility

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, voiceover

My view hierarchy is: A parent view, a container view which is subview of parent view. The container view has multiple labels as a key value pair. Eg: Name: Somename. Something [like](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility_for_ios_and_tvos/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app) under "Simplify Your Accessibility Information" Labels without grouping.

Note: My question is for macOS, I just gave iOS for reference.

VoiceOver reads key and value as separately but I want them to be read as one label and focus also as single label.

I tried to `setAccessibilityFrameInParentSpace` and `NSAccessibilityElement`. But still VoiceOver reads and focus separately.
Code:

```
    func setAccessibility() {
    
    var elements = [NSAccessibilityElement]()
    let groupedElement = NSAccessibilityElement()
    groupedElement.setAccessibilityLabel("\(nameLabel.stringValue), \(nameValue.stringValue)")
    //groupedElement.setAccessibilityFrame(nameLabel.frame.union(nameValue.frame))
    groupedElement.setAccessibilityFrameInParentSpace(nameLabel.frame.union(nameValue.frame))
    elements.append(groupedElement)
    /*
    nameLabel.setAccessibilityLabelUIElements(elements)
    nameValue.setAccessibilityLabelUIElements(elements)
    nameLabel.setAccessibilityLabel("\(nameLabel.stringValue), \(nameValue.stringValue)")
    nameLabel.setAccessibilityFrame(nameLabel.frame.union(nameValue.frame))
    */
    
    containerView.setAccessibilityLabelUIElements([elements])
}
```

I referred macOS [accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/accessibility_for_macos/integrating_accessibility_into_your_app). Something still I'm missing.
Individual labels are set accessibility enabled. Like

```
setAccessibilityElement(true)
setAccessibilityRole(.staticText)
```

Appreciate your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to use [`NSAccessibilityProtocol.setAccessibilityTitleUIElement(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityprotocol/1535605-setaccessibilitytitleuielement). Let's imagine you have a UI which looks like this:

[image]

To associate these two fields, you would use the API like this. Note that you need to associate the CELL of the title field with the control which needs a title:

```
usernameField.setAccessibilityTitleUIElement(usernameLabel.cell)
```

By default, this will lead VoiceOver to announce two elements: "Username:" and "user1 insertion at end of text, Username:, edit text". If users have enabled the
"Skip redundant labels" setting in VoiceOver Utility > Navigation, then VoiceOver wouldn't even land on the Username: label at all.

In addition to doing this in code, you can also make the association easily by dragging from the control's context menu in Xcode:

[image]